# My Documents Path Re-directing to OneDrive Path

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, onedrive, documents

I'll Start with the very simple code

```
    string fileName; // filename of file            

    // get the filename
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
          openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
          openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
          openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
          openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
          fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
    }
```

What i'm trying to do is use the `.Net OpenFileDialog.` and set the `InitialDirectory` to the user who is running the application's My Documents folder.

The code sets the path of Initial Directory to: `C:\Users\Aaron\Documents`, which is the test users My Documents Directory.

When I run the code, the `OpenFileDialog` is actually opening in directory: `C:\Users\Aaron\OneDrive\Documents`. Which is the One Drive location.

This is happening on both my machines, but not my friends machine.

Why is the OneDrive Documents Folder Opening when this is not the Path set to `OpenFIleDialog.InitialDirectory` ?

EDIT: I should probably update this. The following day I ran my project again and the issue was no longer happening. I did not change my code either. It must have been a fluke scenario.

Comment: Side Note: if you want the user's documents, you should use [`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The path to documents can be changed by the user, or as a function of a group policy.

Comment: @theB, very good point. For this particular use case; however, The path is correct. I will edit the question to reflect this better practice though.

Comment: I really don't see any reason why it might be doing that. Have you tried it the `Environment.GetFolderPath` way?

Comment: Yup, I ran it with the Environment.GetFolderPath way before hand. Either way, the Path that InitialDirectory is set to is correct, but when the dialog opens, it opens in the OneDrive documents.

Comment: I cannot recreate this problem. It seems specific to your machine.

Comment: @PCLuddite I just deleted my OneDrive Documents folder, created the dialog, and it opend my `My Documents` folder.  Upon recreating my OneDrive Documents folder and opening the dialog again, it opened there again.. I am at a loss, because the code returns the path for the actual `My Documents` folder.

Comment: I encountered this issue as well. The only workaround I found was to [disable OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-or-uninstall-OneDrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog box should not be opening "OneDrive\Documents". It might be that you have redirected your "Documents" folder to OneDrive's, but because you've more or less hard coded the path, that seems unlikely.

This is why in general you should never assume that the user's documents are located in `C:\Users\{USERNAME}\Documents`. It can be changed by the user or group policy and is not guaranteed to be there in future versions of Windows.

To find the user's "My Documents" folder (or "Documents" on Vista and up) use this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

So your code would be:

```
string fileName; // filename of file            

// get the filename
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
      openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
      openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
      openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
      openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
      fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
}
```

Comment: This makes the code better, but does not solve the original problem of, "Why is the OneDrive documents folder opening?"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:
Dim PersoFolder As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders", "Personal", Nothing)

**No it doesn't when used as the initialDirectory parameter for an openFile dialog!** But this does:

**Dim UserFolders as String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)**

**OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = UserFolders & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms"**

**- UPDATE**

New problem: you can't use UserFolders & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms" for anything other than the openFile initialDirectory parameter! If you use it to try to create a sub-directory, it won't work. The sub-directory becomes "". BUT I have noticed that the string variable created from My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders", "Personal", Nothing) will revert to the correct value i.e. the user's documents folder if you add a sub-folder and use Directory.CreateDirectory(). So there is a simple solution: Use **two String variables**:

**Dim PersoFolder As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders", "Personal", Nothing)**

**Dim UserFolders As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)**

**Dim OpenPersoFolder as String
Dim UserFolders as String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
OpenPersoFolder = UserFolders & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms"**

Then:
**OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = OpenPersoFolder**
But:
**Directory.CreateDirectory(PersoFolder & "\" & [New Folder Name])**

"Curiouser and curiouser!" as Alice once said. If I did not know better I would say someone at Microsoft had been messing about!

P.S. I'm not too bothered if it's verbose or not as long as it works but thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: Semantically identical to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`. The latter is much less verbose than a registry lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross the same problem as you.
I tried the following

```
.initialdirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
.initialdirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\"
.initialdirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
.initialdirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) & "\"
.initialdirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
.initialdirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\"
```

I also tried passing those value to a string variable.
I also tried to directly hardcode my own mydocuments folder for testing and it was always the same behavior. Redirecting to onedrive folder.

Then I changed this property :

```
 .AutoUpgradeEnabled = False
```

And tadam ^^ it opens back to the local mydocuments folder....

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
public static string MyDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).Replace(@"OneDrive\","").Replace(@"\Documents", @"\MyDocuments")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**